# Grails formRemote: specifying real url as parameter

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to use the Grail formRemote tag.  I'm using it like so:

```
<g:formRemote name="newRule" url="https://somesite/somescript">
```

However, I keep getting the error:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.JavascriptTagLib.deepClone() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://somesite/somescript]

How do I specify a real URL in this field instead of a map with controller, action, etc... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the createLink method inside the url attribute?  For example   `<g:formRemote name="someName" url="${createLink(controller:'somescript', base:'https://somesite')}" >`

or you could pass it this way:
url="[controller:'somescript', base:'https://somesite.com']"  Seems to work in my test app.