# Grails SubmitToRemote attribute url

Tags: grails, taglib

I have a question about the submittoremote tag.

In the documentation, for the attribute url, it says we can put either a map or a URL STRING.
It's the second part that interests me.

Here is the exact line from the official documentation:
"url - The url to submit to, either a map contraining keys for the action, controller and id or a string value"

Below, you have my code:

```
<g:submitToRemote url="/test/foo" update="smsForm" class="submitButtonSendForm" value="Envoyer"/>
```

This doesn't work and here is the mistake i get :

No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.JavascriptTagLib.createLink() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/commande/pinRequestWeb] Possible solutions: remoteLink(), remoteLink(groovy.lang.Closure), remoteLink(java.util.Map), remoteLink(java.util.Map, groovy.lang.Closure), remoteLink(java.util.Map, java.lang.CharSequence)

I don't understand this error compare to the documentation ...

Why can't I write down a string in the url attribute as the documentation says ?

Thx for helping me :-)

Answer (score 0):

the `@url` attribute is supposed to have a map for controller mapping:

```
<g:submitToRemote url="[ controller:'test', action:'foo' ]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one and it's working fine :

`<g:submitToRemote url="[controller:'book',action: 'submit']" update="actualResponse" value="Submit"/>`

You can also refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173644/grails-formremote-specifying-real-url-as-parameter) for the exception you are facing it's quite similar to the answer I provided.